# Django - How to save an object from a model in a view

Tags: python, html, django

I'm running Django 1.10 on Python 3.7.

I have a problem when I try to save an object from a model after applying a function on it.

What I want to do is just to substract a certain amount of money (this amount is stored in the class (`klient`) attribute `argent`).
Then, I created a method called `acheter` in this class with an argument `id_achat` to be able to substract different amounts of money.

When I run the command `a.acheter(id_achat)` (where *a* is a `klient` object and `id_achat` an integer) in the shell, everything is OK, the substraction has been done when I run `a.argent`.

However, in `interface_du_klient.html`, I put some links to redirect the user to a view called `achat`. In this view I call the `acheter` method on my `klient` object called with the `get_object_or_404` method, but the attribute `argent` of this `klient` object is not modified.

**Here you can see my `models.py` :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
import decimal

class klient(models.Model):
    id_klient=models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    nom=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prenom=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    argent=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    membre=models.IntegerField() # 0 pour non membre, 1 pour membre KFet
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, 
                                verbose_name="Date d'enregistrement")
    nombre_biere=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    nombre_pinte=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    nombre_cafe_ou_the=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    nombre_canette=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.nom,self.prenom)
    def acheter(self,id_achat):
        if self.membre==0:
            a=1
        else:
            a=0.8
        if id_achat==1:          # id_achat : {1:bière 33cl, 2:bière 25cl, 3:pinte, 4:café/thé, 5:canette}
            self.argent=self.argent-decimal.Decimal(3*a)
            self.nombre_biere+=1                            ## bière 33cl
            self.save()
        elif id_achat==2:
            self.argent=self.argent-decimal.Decimal(2.2*a)
            self.nombre_biere+=1                            ## bière 25cl
            self.save()
        elif id_achat==3:
            self.argent=self.argent-decimal.Decimal(2*a)
            self.nombre_pinte+=1                            ## pinte Blondi
            self.save()
        elif id_achat==4:
            self.argent=self.argent-decimal.Decimal(0.4*a)
            self.nombre_cafe_ou_the+=1                      ## café/thé
            self.save()
        elif id_achat==5:
            self.argent=self.argent-decimal.Decimal(0.8*a)
            self.nombre_canette+=1                          ## canette
            self.save()
        pass

class achetables(models.Model):
    nom=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prix=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=4)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.prix)
```

**Here is my `views.py` :**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from kfet.models import klient,achetables
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

from datetime import datetime


def date_actuelle(request):
    return render(request, 'kfet/date.html', {'date': datetime.now()})

def accueil(request):
    liste_tokards=klient.objects.all()
    return render(request, "kfet/accueil.html",{'liste_tokards': liste_tokards})

def interface_du_klient(request,id_ienkli):
    produits=achetables.objects.all()
    klient_selec=get_object_or_404(klient, id_klient=id_ienkli)
    liste_tokards=klient.objects.all()
    if id_ienkli==0:
        return render(request, "kfet/accueil.html", {'liste_tokards': liste_tokards})
    else:
        return render(request, "kfet/interface_du_klient.html", {'client': klient_selec}, {'liste_produits' : produits})

def achat(request,id_bouffon,id_ach):
    klient_selec=get_object_or_404(klient, id_klient=id_bouffon)
    klient_selec.acheter(id_ach)
    return interface_du_klient(request,id_bouffon)
```

**Here is my `interface_klient.html` :**

```
<h1>Bienvenue sur le site de la KFet !</h1>


<h3>Compte de {{client.nom}} {{client.prenom}}. Il y a {{client.argent}} euros sur son compte.</h3>



<p><a href="{% url "accueil" %}">Retour accueil</a>

<p><a href="{% url "achat" id_bouffon=client.id_klient id_ach=1 %}">Acheter biere 33cl</a>

<p><a href="{% url "achat" id_bouffon=client.id_klient id_ach=2 %}">Acheter biere 25cl</a>

<p><a href="{% url "achat" id_bouffon=client.id_klient id_ach=3 %}">Acheter pinte Blondi</a>
```

If you want to see my `urls.py`, I can edit my post but I think it doesn't come from this file.

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to help me.

Comment: How do you know it's not being updated?  What happens if you refresh `interface_klient.html'?

Comment: In `interface_du_klient.html` I can see the value of the attribute `argent` of the selected `klient`and it still has the same value. I can also see this by running `one_klient.argent` in the shell and by looking at the administration.